Missing semicolon in unit test
I'm trying to test a controller using Jest, but I get the following error:
SyntaxError: C:\Users\alexi\Desktop\blog\blogme\back\src\__tests__\articleController.test.ts: Missing semicolon. (7:17)

  5 |
  6 | describe('createArticle Controller', () => {
> 7 |   let mockRequest: Partial<Request>;
      |                  ^
  8 |   let mockResponse: Partial<Response>;
  9 |   let nextFunction: NextFunction;
 10 |

Test File: src/__tests__/articleController.test.ts:
    import { createArticle } from '../controllers/articleController';
    import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
    import prismaMock from '../__mocks__/prisma/client'; // Prisma mock

    describe('createArticle Controller', () => {
      let mockRequest: Partial<Request>;
      let mockResponse: Partial<Response>;
      let nextFunction: NextFunction;

      beforeEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks(); // Clear mocks before each test

        mockRequest = {
          user: {
            id: 1,
            email: 'test@example.com',
          },
          body: {
            title: 'Test Article',
            content: 'This is a test.',
          },
        };

     mockResponse = {
      status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      json: jest.fn(),
    };

     nextFunction = jest.fn();
    });

    it('should create an article successfully', async () => {
    (prismaMock.article.create as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValue({
      id: 1,
      title: 'Test Article',
      content: 'This is a test.',
      authorId: 1,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      updatedAt: new Date(),
    });

    await createArticle(mockRequest as Request, mockResponse as Response, nextFunction);

    expect(prismaMock.article.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      data: {
        title: 'Test Article',
        content: 'This is a test.',
        authorId: 1,
      },
    });
    expect(mockResponse.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(201);
    expect(mockResponse.json).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      expect.objectContaining({
        id: 1,
        title: 'Test Article',
        content: 'This is a test.',
        authorId: 1,
      })
    );
    expect(nextFunction).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});

Mock File: src/__mocks__/prisma/client.ts:
const prismaMock = {
     article: {
    create: jest.fn(),
    findUnique: jest.fn(),
    update: jest.fn(),
    delete: jest.fn(),
    },
    user: {
    findUnique: jest.fn(),
    },
    };

    jest.mock('../prisma/client', () => ({
     __esModule: true,
     default: prismaMock,
    }));

export default prismaMock;

Jest Configuration: jest.config.ts:
    import type { Config } from '@jest/types';

    const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
     preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    transform: {
     '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',  
    },
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'json', 'node'],
    };

export default config;

I tried creating a babel.config.ts file following Jest documentation, but it didn't help. A simple test using TypeScript worked perfectly, but this one keeps throwing the error.
What could be causing this SyntaxError? Is my Jest configuration missing something? Do I need additional Babel or TypeScript setup for Jest to handle TypeScript files properly?
Additional information:

Jest version: ^29.5.14
ts-jest version: ^29.2.5
TypeScript version: ^5.7.2

